# Integral representation of $f(x)=0^x$

Tags: exponentiation, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, mathematica, divergent-integrals

Recently I had an argument with Luboš Motl on Quora, where he had argued that $0^0$ should be left undefined in computer algebra systems, because $x^y$ has no limit at $(0,0)$ and $0^x=0$ at all $x>0$.

So, I decided to represent the function $0^x$ in integral form. Once heaving a universal representation of the function one would be able to see what its value at $x=0$ is (as well as around that point).

For that purpose, I armed myself with divergent integrals, Laplace transforms, etc, etc.

So, assuming that

$$0^{-n}=\frac{W^{n+1}-w^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

where

$$w^n=B_n(0)+n\int_0^\infty B_{n-1}(x)dx$$

and

$$W^n=B_n(1)+n\int_0^\infty B_{n-1}(x+1)dx$$

I obtained the following formula:

$$0^x=\frac{B_{1-x}(1)-B_{1-x}+\int_0^{\infty } (x-1) x t^{-x-1} \, dt}{\Gamma (2-x)}=$$
$$\frac{(x-1) \zeta (x,1)-(x-1) \zeta (x,0)+\int_0^{\infty } (x-1) x t^{-x-1} \, dt}{\Gamma (2-x)}$$

The formula with Bernoulli polynomials works well in Mathematica at positive and negative integer $x$, as well as at zero, returning expected divergent integrals or finite values, but the formula with Hurwitz Zeta fails at positive integers, returning expression with the symbol `ComplexInfinity`.

The both formulas fail at non-integer $x$. So, I wonder, whether it is possible to re-write these formulas in such a way that I would always obtain a convergent or divergent integral?

I tried to apply the integral representations of Hurwitz Zeta function from Wikipedia, but those return wrong results outside of their range of validity (unlike the built-in functions).

Comment: The status of $\,0^0\,$ is a well-known matter of convention and opinion. Some prefer to make it undefinied while others want $\,0^0=1.\,$ As for Mathematica, It is easy enough to use `Unprotect[Power]; 0^0 = 1; Protect[Power];` if that is what you want. Trying to use integrals, etc., is not solving the real problem.